# SwiftUI App only install framework(SwiftUI) not it's dependency(SDK.framework)

Tags: swift, swiftui, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I'm encountering a challenge when integrating a UI framework as a local pod into an app project. The UI framework itself builds successfully, and I've embedded a pre-built fat framework as a dependency within the UI framework. However, when I use the UI framework as a local pod in the app, the dependent SDK is not being installed or linked correctly.

Steps Taken:

Embedded SDK: I've embedded the fat framework for the dependent SDK within the UI framework project by dragging and dropping it into the Frameworks group and checking the "Embed" checkbox.

Added a framework search path in the UI framework pointing to the SDK

Local Pod: I've created a local pod for the UI framework by following appropriate podspec creation guidelines. This podspec likely doesn't include any specific configuration for the dependent SDK.

I also tried to add the SDK as a dependency in the UI framework's podspec, but it couldn't be done because the SDK is only on my local machine.

Expected behaviour:

When I install the local pod for the UI framework in the app project, I expect both the UI framework and the dependent SDK to be included and accessible.

Actual behaviour:

Only the UI framework is installed, and the app fails to compile due to missing symbols or references from the dependent SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding the below lines in my UI framework's podspec.

```
s.frameworks = "SDK_NAME"
s.vendored_frameworks = 'any_folder/SDK_NAME.framework'
```

along with these line I placed 'any_folder/SDK_NAME.framework' in same folder where I have my podspec for UI framework.

```
root
|
|_ UI_Framework_Name.podspec
|
|_ any_folder/SDK_NAME.framework or SDK_NAME.framework
```